# How to send additional data in request while uploading images in django-ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor, image-uploading, django-ckeditor

I am using django-ckeditor for users to enter rich text on my site's webpages.Every webpage on my site represents a document with a unique id.

For ex- two separate documents will have two web pages with URLs such as -

```
example.com/documents/doc1 and example.com/documents/doc2
```

Each of these 2 web pages have multiple CKEDITORs.I want that when user uploads image through CKEDITORs on webpage- example.com/documents/doc1 should go to a separate directory

```
/media/uploads/doc1/
```

and images uploaded through CKEDITORs on webpage example.com/documents/doc2 should go to a separate directory -

```
/media/uploads/doc2/
```

Now the problem arises here.In the upload view method in views.py of django-ckeditor module -

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Uploads a file and send back its URL to CKEditor.
    """
    # Get the uploaded file from request.
    upload = request.FILES['upload']

    #Verify that file is a valid image
    backend = image_processing.get_backend()
    try:
        backend.image_verify(upload)
    except utils.NotAnImageException:
        return HttpResponse("""
                   <script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('Invalid image')
                        window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({0});
                   </script>""".format(request.GET['CKEditorFuncNum']))

    # Open output file in which to store upload.
    upload_filename = get_upload_filename(upload.name, request.user)
    saved_path = default_storage.save(upload_filename, upload)

    if backend.should_create_thumbnail(saved_path):
        backend.create_thumbnail(saved_path)

    url = utils.get_media_url(saved_path)

    # Respond with Javascript sending ckeditor upload url.
    return HttpResponse("""
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({0}, '{1}');
    </script>""".format(request.GET['CKEditorFuncNum'], url))
```

upload_filename is defined as ***get_upload_filename(upload.name,request.user)***

It takes filename and request.user as parameters and stores files in user specific folders.How can I pass the docid from my url to the post request so that I can use docid to store images in the document-centric folders?

I hope my point is understood.If any more information is needed then please let me know in the comments, I would add those. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the config.filebrowserUploadUrl:

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/upload.php?docid=" + docid;
```

Comment: I am using a django backend,not php backend

Comment: Then use upload.py instead of upload.php Do you really want me to guess the url that you're using in the CKEditor configuration?